# How to get path images in Bigcommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

How can I get path images in Bigcommerce? I upload my folder image to server of BC but they're not show in admin. I use stencil theme in Bigcommerce.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All your images should be available under your domain name. For example:

https://www.petswarehouse.com/product_images/PU-203P-B.jpg

The folder you are pointing at should be in:

```
https://www.petswarehouse.com/product_images/petfoodexperts/{imagename}
```

Comment: Is this still the case because I can only see images on the Big Commerce? i.e. https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/...